# 404 error when referencing fileUpload interceptor in Struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, http-status-code-404

I am using `struts.xml` file which is described below :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />
   
   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
      
      <interceptors>
         <interceptor name="myinterceptor"
            class="com.struts2examples.MyInterceptor" />
         <interceptor name="myinterceptor1"
            class="com.struts2examples.MyInterceptor1" />
         
      </interceptors>
      
      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptor1"/>
      </action>
      
      <action name="hello1" 
            class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction1" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="freemarker">
                <param name="location">/hello.fm</param>
            </result>
            <result name="nopassnofail" type="redirect">
                <param name="location">/NewWorld.jsp</param >
            </result>
            <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
      </action>
      
      <action name="upload" class="com.struts2examples.UploadFile" method="execute">
      
       <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
           <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
       </interceptor-ref>
       <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
       <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

It was working before I added the last action `upload`. When I start the server it is showing me the 404 error. Can somebody help me out in resolving the issue. I am feeling that the issue is due to `<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add after `<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">` `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">`. If you add explicit interceptor to the action the `defaultStack` disappears.

Comment: No it is not solving the problem. I am getting a 404 on server.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write like this and try again

```
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
   <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```