# File upload interceptor does not call setter methods

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2

I need to do very basic file upload operation, but in my case setter methods are not called by file upload interceptor.

I have checked the solution of similar questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733554/struts-2-file-upload-file-object-being-null) on stackoverflow but they didnot resolve my issue.

Please let me know what mistake i am doing in code.

**Action class**

```
public class ResultFileUploadAction extends ActionSupport {
    private File upload;
    private String uploadFileName;
    private String uploadContentType;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        logger.info("ResultFileUploadAction->execute");
        String destPath = "C:/work/";
        try {
            System.out.println("Src File name: " + upload);
            System.out.println("Dst File name: " + uploadFileName);
            File destFile = new File(destPath, uploadFileName);
            FileUtils.copyFile(upload, destFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }

        return super.execute();
    }

    public void setUpload(File upload) {
        this.upload = upload;
    }

    public void setUploadContentType(String uploadContentType) {
        this.uploadContentType = uploadContentType;
    }

    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }
}
```

**Jsp file**

```
<body>

    <s:form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="upload" id="uploadfile" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
    </s:form>
</body>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="fileupload"
        class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor"></interceptor>
    <interceptor name="servletConfig"
        class="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor" />
    <interceptor name="authenticationinterceptor"
        class="interceptors.common.AuthenticationInterceptor"></interceptor>
    <interceptor-stack name="securestack">
        <interceptor-ref name="authenticationinterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"></interceptor-ref>

    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<action name="upload" class="actions.result.ResultFileUploadAction"
    method="execute">
    <interceptor-ref name="securestack"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="fileupload"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success" type="dispatcher">/AddResultBullk.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Since, setters are not called therefore i am getting `NPE` in `execute()`.

Comment: AFAIK this won't work without the regular params interceptor. By stripping out almost all the framework's default interceptors you run the risk of eliminating a lot of functionality--in general I don't recommend doing such a thing. Please double-check using a fuller interceptor stack.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right, fileupload works with defaultstack, but this is not mentioned in javadoc that this interceptor must be used in conjunction with some ( don't know which one ) interceptor within default stack. There should be a note atleast.

Comment: The file upload docs states that the interceptor "adds parameters", which to me means it needs the params interceptor.

Comment: Uploading without interceptor, doesn't work. Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20071814/573032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the `fileUpload` interceptor docs:

> It adds the following parameters, where [File Name] is the name given to the file uploaded by the HTML form. [fileName, contentType]

When mucking with interceptor stacks there are always two plans of attack:

- Try a non-custom stack
- Don't mess with the stack unless you know precisely why you're doing it, and what you're doing.

Also, actions that are configured to use almost no interceptors, as yours is, are almost always suspect, because they eliminate the bulk of framework functionality. Params in particular is key to essentially every form-based action.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to implements a new interceptors, it is a good idea to add them to the default stack in front or back of the chain, i faced the same problem before when I am trying to add an interceptor for authentication and ended with the following practice, I will update your 
code to mention my idea:

```
...
<interceptors>    
    <interceptor name="authenticationinterceptor" class="your.class.name" />
    <interceptor-stack name="securestack">
        <interceptor-ref name="authenticationinterceptor" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<!--
Implicitly use securestack for all actions.
-->
<default-interceptor-ref name="securestack" />
....
<!-- 
and if you want some actions to pass from secureStack and use defaultStack
(ex login page), you can state that explicitly, See:
-->
<action name="GetLoginPageAction" class="your.class.name">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    ...
</action>

<!-- 
for upload action you can use interceptor without define 
it in the interceptors tag only in the action, 
Note that you should explicitly use securestack below
-->
<action name="upload" class="actions.result.ResultFileUploadAction">
    <!-- You can remove the below refs because fileUpload is already 
         included in defaultStack that is included in the securestack 
         and securestack is default interceptor for all actions.
    <interceptor-ref name="securestack"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
    -->
    ...
</action>
```

I hope these notes help you.

Comment: I did the same. Thanks for confirming my implementation.